# measuring the performance of round-trips on stocks

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, performance-evaluation

can you provide me with some ideas to assess the profitability of round-trips? That is when I buy 100 shares of IBM at 10\$ and I resell them two days later at 11\$, how can I measure the profit made? Using which benchmark? How can I compare two round-trips on different stocks at different points in time? What do practitioners do in Banks/funds?

Comment: what is your funding cost?

Comment: cash or I can leverage up to 4x and paying an additional transaction cost